# HTML and CSS Submenu doesn't show in this code

Tags: html, css

I'm creating an a new project usingo HTML, CSS for front-end and Flask for back-end but in HTML and CSS, i have a problem: submenu class doesn't appears in the page.

There is the code:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/basic/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/nav.css">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Loader -->
    <div class="loader">
        <div class="logo_loader">
            <img src="/static/basic/item.png" alt="" class="image1">
            <img src="/static/basic/bg.png" alt="" class="image2">
        </div>
    </div>

    <header class="hed pos rel">
        <a href="/" class="home_nav_bar_a">
            <img src="/static/basic/favicon.png" alt="Home icon">
        </a>
        <nav class="hed nav">
            <ul>
                {% for rl in links_core %}
                    <li>
                        <a href='{{ rl.url }}'>{{ rl.name }}</a>
                        {% if not rl.menus == false %}
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                {% for srl in rl.menus %}
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ srl.url }}">{{ srl.name }}</a>
                                    </li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        {% endif %}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- Required script -->
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            const loaderContainer = document.querySelector('.loader');
            loaderContainer.style.display = 'none';
        });
    </script>
    <noscript>
            <style>
                .loader {
                    display: none;
                }
            </style>
    </noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

And CSS code:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.hed {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.hed .pos .abs {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.hed .pos .rel {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.hed .pos .fix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.home_nav_bar_a {
    float: left;
    margin: 2.5px 5px;
    padding: 2.5px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.home_nav_bar_a img {
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
}

.hed nav {
    float: right;
}

.hed nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}

.hed nav ul li {
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.hed nav ul li a {
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1786F9;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.hed nav ul li a:hover {
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #00FEFB;
}

.submenu {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
}

.hed nav ul li:hover .submenu {
    display: block;
}

.submenu li {
    margin: 0;
}

.submenu li a {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    color: #1786F9;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.submenu li a:hover {
    color: #00FEFB;
}
```

I'm tried to fix it but doesn't work.

Comment: Can you pls create a html/css/js StackBlitz? Just copy the produced html from the browser's inspector (f12)